# MaterializeCSS Using Icon As FAB Button [FeatureDiscovery]

Tags: css, materialize

On the FeatureDiscovery page they have a FAB button in the bottom right hand corner (http://materializecss.com/feature-discovery.html). I would like to replace this button with a .png image - a circular image like this: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/3b/44/d4/3b44d4a91a8cd625984fb30451cf6686.png. Is this possible at all?

If so would you be able to guide me into how to do it please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/cesjen4a/2/) for you. Do you mean something like this?

```css
#icon {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fab-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="icon">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img class="fab-img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/3b/44/d4/3b44d4a91a8cd625984fb30451cf6686.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also replace the `<i class="material-icons">menu</i>` with the img tag included in the snippet

Comment: That seems brilliant thanks Zowie. Is it also possible to make it work like a FAB expanding button?

Comment: @user1149620 Yeah sure i will make one for you :)

Comment: That would be ace. I understand how the expanding FAB works (for example on this page: http://materializecss.com/buttons.html) - I am just unsure how to replace that with my own image as above! Sorry if I was unclear. Thanks again for all the help Zowie.

Comment: @user1149620 Here you go mate. Changed the fab to a nav menu so its easier to edit. And all images are now background images. also added a tooltip that's what people nowadays use in front of their fab menus.

Fiddle here https://fiddle.jshell.net/epg9mkh5/

Comment: Wow that is absolutely perfect, thanks for doing that and explaining how it works as well. Thanks.

Comment: @user1149620 No problem :)

Comment: @user1149620 your recent fiddle is not found.